# React Native array prop confuse

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-props

I have two components, a parent (`ManySpace`) and a child (`OtherComponent`). `OtherComponent` renders two `ManySpace` components with two different arrays for the `manyspace` prop.

MANYSPACE1 and MANYSPACE2 render is perfect, but confuse the first ManySpace and second ManySpace component array contents how I solve this problem thanks.
hope I to explained the my problem

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
  let MANYSPACE;
  let icerik;
  let firsttext;
  let firstinput;
  let answer1;
  let answerlength1;
  let secondtext;
  let secondinput;
class ManySpace extends Component {
  render() {
    MANYSPACE = this.props.manyspace;
    icerik = MANYSPACE[0].icerik;
    firsttext = MANYSPACE[0].firsttext;
    firstinput = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput;
    if (firstinput) {
      answer1 = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput.answer1;
      answerlength1 = answer1.length;
    }

    secondtext = MANYSPACE[0].secondtext;
    secondinput = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput;
    if (secondinput) {
      answer2 = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput.answer2;
      answerlength2 = answer2.length;
    }
  return (

  ) 
}
```

--My other component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; //and other imports
  const MANYSPACE1 = [
    {
      icerik: 'lorem ipsum',
      firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
      firstinput: {
        answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
      },
      secondtext: 'lorem ipsum'
    }
  ];
  const MANYSPACE2 = [
    {
      icerik:'lorem ipsum',
      firsttext: 'lorem ipsum',
      firstinput: {
        answer1: 'lorem ipsum'
      },
      secondtext: 'lorem ipsum',
      secondinput: {
        answer2: 'lorem ipsum'
      },
      thirdinput: {
        answer3: 'lorem ipsum'
      }
    }
  ];  
class OtherComponent extends Component {
    <ManySpace
      manyspace={MANYSPACE1}
    />
    <ManySpace
     manyspace={MANYSPACE2}
    />
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create your variables inside of the `render` method instead of sharing a single variable for all `ManySpace` instances.

**Example**

```
import React, { Component } from "react"; //and other imports

class ManySpace extends Component {
  render() {
    const MANYSPACE = this.props.manyspace;
    const { icerik, firsttext, firstinput } = MANYSPACE[0];
    let answer1, answerlength1;

    if (firstinput) {
      answer1 = MANYSPACE[0].firstinput.answer1;
      answerlength1 = answer1.length;
    }

    const { secondtext, secondinput } = MANYSPACE[0];
    let answer2, answerlength2;

    if (secondinput) {
      answer2 = MANYSPACE[0].secondinput.answer2;
      answerlength2 = answer2.length;
    }

    return (
      {/* ... */}
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but my fault Iam using variables outside the render scope I try and secondinput not avaible warning, my outside the render function like so how I do that                                                                                        
 onSubmitEditing1 = () => {
    if (secondinput) {
      this.secondref.focus();
    } else if (thirdinput) {
      this.thirdref.focus();
    } else {
      Keyboard.dismiss();
    }
  };

Comment: @Radex26 Don't update the question once it has been answered. Accept an answer to this question if you feel it has been answered and create an entirely new question.

Comment: Okay sorry you right, my bad I forgot this piece, but how I solve this issue, if you can solve I'm satisfied